# Recently custom flagged post for incorrect answer was declined

Tags: support, flags, wrong-answers

Recently I flagged a post with a custom for incorrect code and got this:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

question: why should I try to get the post either deleted or corrected when the
moderators don't care about incorrect syntax or if the code simply does not work?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood that flag response. That is actually default text that the network provides for moderators' use because that is the standard response to "this answer is wrong" flags. This site doesn't ask moderators to judge the correctness of an answer - it's really impossible to expect them to be experts in all subjects on the site. If you find an answer is incorrect, then downvote it. Flagging it is not the appropriate choice.

Comment: I also edited it with the correct code but the edit was declined.

Comment: I understand the moderators are not fluent in all programming dialects.

Comment: If you find a wrong answer and no one has written the correct answer yet, don't fix the wrong answer, answer the question yourself with the necessary information.

Comment: It still annoys me that the poster refuses to correct his code.

Comment: Note that the author didn't reject your edit; two other people did. It's critical when submitting fixes that you explain *in as much detail as possible* what you're doing and why - otherwise they tend to be rejected out of hand.

Comment: So i should be more descriptive when editing someones post in order to get it accepted?

Comment: It's worth a shot; something more than "corrected code for syntax and readability" would at least give reviewers a better idea of what they should look for (and maybe motivation to skip if they don't feel like doing so)

Comment: It's not entirely obvious, but eoredson raised several custom moderator flags with specific details, @Stephen; most of the guidance WRT not-an-answer flags isn't all that relevant in those cases.

Comment: So overall there's nothing i can do about obviously incorrect code.

Comment: I think Shog's answer does a great job of telling you that what you did was a good attempt to address the situation... you wrote comments, suggested edits... one of your edits was approved, even... there's some room for improvement (edit reasons) but *in this situation*, it seems like you've made the grand attempt and it didn't pan out. Maybe next time it will. :)

Comment: Utter agreement. I'll skip the obvious and work towards something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Moderators often cannot judge the accuracy of a post, and even more often shouldn't try; in particularly severe situations they may step up to remove harmful misinformation, but normally won't remove answers that make a good effort to solve the problem even if their attempt produces incorrect results.

There's usually no harm in letting an obviously-wrong answer sit at the bottom of the list; as long as a correct answer ranks above it, downvotes will suffice to keep it out of the way.

Not that you should feel bad about *trying* to help improve it; from what I can see, you did everything you could. But, at the end of the day the author has as much right to their post as you do to yours, and if they want it to be wrong you should respect that. And downvote.

Comment: I would like downvoting an answer would improve the post but it does not.

Comment: Perhaps there could be a crew of programmers in stack overflow to be hired who's job would be to correct code in posts!?

Comment: @eoredson: If the author doesn't want to improve their post and learn from their mistakes, it's on them, not you or anyone else.

Comment: Ok, then there is nothing i can do about it...

Comment: Downvoting does improve the post, in a way, @eoredson . It's acts as a signal to the users who have the same problem that the answer may not be correct or trustworthy, encouraging them to find another solution... perhaps the top voted one.

Answer (score 9):

To add to Shog9's answer, and provide context: you and another user provided answers to a question. You stated in the comments on their answer that their answer was wrong and wouldn't compile. They responded and said that it did compile, and that you were testing it incorrectly. They also stated that your answer was incorrect, and provided reasons for why that was (this comment was voted up by someone else).

After this, you flagged their answer as "not an answer" and had that flag disputed in review (it most likely would have been declined if seen by a moderator). You suggested two edits to the post, which were accepted. You then flagged it with the following custom flag:

> The OP was posting 30 days ago with an invalid code response that does not work as advertised on any basic ide or compiler and should be deleted.

which was declined. You then re-flagged it with:

> This answer was posted months ago and I have tried to get the original poster in comments to repair it because it does not produce correct output. I have also edited it several times but it still does not display what it says: to convert case of strings.

and had that declined again with the above. An additional suggested edit that rewrote the answer was also declined in review.

In this case we have two people who are arguing that the other is wrong. Who do we trust? Do we just take your word for it and remove the answer that competes with you? What if they made the same claims and asked for your answer to be deleted? They did say you were wrong, after all.

This is why moderators almost always decline flags that ask us to delete incorrect answers or comments. You really don't want a small group of people going around and removing answers that they think are wrong. It's also nearly impossible for every technology on this site to be represented among the pool of moderators. Stack Overflow is simply too broad.

The whole point of this site is that the community decides what is and is not correct via voting. Using moderators to delete incorrect answers short-circuits that and reduces trust in the system. If you see something that is wrong, vote it down, point out what is wrong with it, and / or provide your own answer that you believe to be correct. If you've made a strong enough argument, let the community decide who is and isn't correct via votes. Yes, there are occasional failures of this system, but overall it works well.

Comment: That is a nice overview of my stackoverflow activity and explains many things to me i would not have otherwise understood. Thank you.